# I want to change fontsize in textflow or label

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, font-size, draw2d, textflow

I'm implementing multiline Label Figure.

I have a question.

How can i change font size of textflow ?

I tried with the method [textflow.setFont] before I had changed height value of fontdata.

use this code,`Font tFont = m_Textflow.getFont();
FontData[] tFontDataList = tFont.getFontData();
tFontDataList[0].setHeight(aSize);
m_Textflow.setFont(new Font(null, tFontDataList[0]));`

But that didn’t work correctly and made any space on head.

Help me please T^T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the Font API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html). You'll find the constructor

> `Font(String name, int style, int size)` -
>
> Creates a new Font from the specified name, style and point size.

So you could do something like

```
String family = textFlow.getFont().getFamily();
int style = textFlow.getFont().getStyle();
int theNewFontSize = 30;
textFlow.setFont(new Font(family, style, theNewFontSize));
```

Comment: Thanks your comment :)

"textFlow.getFont()" returns org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font type. And I can't use thoes method T^T
So I tried like your code.

`Font tFont = m_Textflow.getFont();
FontData[] tFontDataList = tFont.getFontData();
String tFontName = tFontDataList[0].getName();
int tFontStyle = tFontDataList[0].getStyle();
m_Textflow.setFont(new Font(Workbench.getInstance().getDisplay(), tFontName, aSize, tFontStyle));`

but it didn't work well.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you using Swing/AWT. I'm Not familiar with SWT

Comment: thanks peeskillet :) your comment helps me. but i will find another way T^T